# System i SQL WITH SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: sql

I have the SQL below in place, and it has an unacceptable response time.

This is used with a DECLARE, PREPARE, OPEN and FETCH in an RPG Program where the selected fields are placed in host variables, populated in an array and then sorted [descending] for subfile display.

The 2 tables in use are not keyed at all (PFs), and they are joined below as shown in the WHERE clause.

```
Select DISTINCT B.Fld1, B.Fld2, B.Fld3, B.Fld4,
A.Fld1, A.Fld2, A.Fld3, A.Fld4, A.Fld5, A.Fld6, A.Fld7, A.Fld8, A.Fld9
From TableA A, TableB B
Where A.Fld2 = B.Fld5
And A.Fld1 = B.Fld6 || B.Fld7
And ((A.Fld7 BETWEEN <from-date> and <to-date>)
Or (A.Fld5 BETWEEN <from-date> and <to-date>))
```

I have rewritten this as a “true” left join, with no improvement.

I have also used 2 available LFs with A.Fld2 and A.Fld1 as keys, with minor improvement.

I feel a recursive SQL could do the trick, but I lack the experience to whip it out.  I have the selects from each table created and functioning as desired by themselves.  I just don’t know how to put them together into one beautiful beast to get the result I desire.

This result set is roughly 10,000 rows for a week time period, and I need to see 2 weeks.

There are almost 6,000,000 records in TableA and about 160,000 in TableB.

Right now, the logic is

1. Run a simple SQL before the one above.
2. Cursor through the records and populate an array
3. Run the SQL above.
4. Cursor through the records and append to the same array
5. Sort the array and use it to populate the subfile.

In debugging, I verified that the SQL above is the meat of the problem.

Truth is that I have 3 files that I believe can be joined into 1 result table to build the subfile.
If I can get past the query above, then ‘I think I can’ handle joining the other file.

My guess is there is someone out there that can “Whip this Out”!  I once worked with him!

This is not an RPG, system i question.  I have laid down some SQL like this in RPG before. Problem was that someone else wrote the SQL. : (

Comment: What does `And A.Fld1 = B.Fld6 || B.Fld7` mean. String concatenation?

Comment: @wildplasser: yes of course. `||` is the standard string concatenation operator in SQL.

Comment: '+' is the standard concatenation operator for SQL server.  || is the concatenation operator for Oracle.

Comment: @w0051977 - I think that @a_horse_with_no_name means that the double pipe is the `ANSI` method of concatenating strings. TSQL doesn't use it but it doesn't mean that its not a standard

Comment: Well, in that case it looks clear to me that the engine has no other choice than *for every row in B tat matches the `A.Fld2 = B.Fld5` restriction, actually perform the string concatenation. If the a.Fld1 has an index on it, and/or the  `A.Fld2 = B.Fld5` condition is very restrictive this is not a big deal, but in other cases it could cost. But without table definitions it's hard to say of course.

Comment: I'm not sure what the SQL is being evaluated against, probably because I'm not familiar with RPG. In an RDBMS the solution lies in defining the right indexes, not sure if that is an option for you in your usage scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting performance issues with the OR (or ||) statement in the join, and maybe from the BETWEEN (which has never worked well for me on DATETIMEs).  Remove both the "Or" and the "||" statements and instead have four separate queries with a "UNION ALL" in between them.  That will greatly improve your performance, even if it seems counterintuitive.  I'd also set that date to [date]>fromDate and [date]

---

UPDATE - here's the complete query without the OR clauses.  The >/< symbols can get hard to read, so have some coffee first:

```
Select DISTINCT B.Fld1, B.Fld2, B.Fld3, B.Fld4,
A.Fld1, A.Fld2, A.Fld3, A.Fld4, A.Fld5, A.Fld6, A.Fld7, A.Fld8, A.Fld9
From TableA A, TableB B
Where A.Fld2 = B.Fld5
And A.Fld1 = B.Fld6
And A.Fld7 > <from-date> 
AND A.Fld7 < <to-date>
AND A.Fld5 < <from-date> -- Excluding these to avoid duplicates
and A.Fld5 > <to-date> -- Excluding these to avoid duplicates
UNION ALL
Select DISTINCT B.Fld1, B.Fld2, B.Fld3, B.Fld4,
A.Fld1, A.Fld2, A.Fld3, A.Fld4, A.Fld5, A.Fld6, A.Fld7, A.Fld8, A.Fld9
From TableA A, TableB B
Where A.Fld2 = B.Fld5
And A.Fld1 = B.Fld6
AND A.Fld5 > <from-date> 
and A.Fld5 < <to-date>
UNION ALL
Select DISTINCT B.Fld1, B.Fld2, B.Fld3, B.Fld4,
A.Fld1, A.Fld2, A.Fld3, A.Fld4, A.Fld5, A.Fld6, A.Fld7, A.Fld8, A.Fld9
From TableA A, TableB B
Where A.Fld2 = B.Fld5
And A.Fld1 = B.Fld7
And A.Fld7 > <from-date> 
AND A.Fld7 < <to-date>
AND A.Fld5 < <from-date> -- Excluding these to avoid duplicates
and A.Fld5 > <to-date> -- Excluding these to avoid duplicates
UNION ALL
Select DISTINCT B.Fld1, B.Fld2, B.Fld3, B.Fld4,
A.Fld1, A.Fld2, A.Fld3, A.Fld4, A.Fld5, A.Fld6, A.Fld7, A.Fld8, A.Fld9
From TableA A, TableB B
Where A.Fld2 = B.Fld5
And A.Fld1 = B.Fld7
AND A.Fld5 > <from-date> 
and A.Fld5 < <to-date>
```

Comment: I am still going to try this approach. I will let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: The `||` operator is string concatenation, not SQL `OR` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given SELECT statement, you want to start the query from TableA, as that is where you want to get the entries based on date/timestamp values in Fld7 and Fld5. First, you want these two columns to be indexed. Both need to have own index.

You should first check what is the performance of getting the data from TableA. You can do this by executing SELECT statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM TableA
 WHERE 
   (A.Fld7 BETWEEN <from-date> and <to-date>) OR
   (A.Fld5 BETWEEN <from-date> and <to-date>)
```

If this already has insufficient performance, then the problem is in TableA indexing. 
You can also consider adding other colums with INCLUDE definition to those indexes. Maybe at least fields Fld1 and Fld2 that you use to join to TableB.

Once you have sufficient performance for TableA, you need to make it to join efficiently to TableB. The  `A.Fld1 = B.Fld6 || B.Fld7` looks quite problematic. I would hope that `B.Fld5` is relatively unique within TableB, in which case it is enought that you have index for Fld5 in TableB. The A.Fld1 check would be in the join just to eliminate out small amount of rows that you get with joining `A.Fld2 = B.Fld5`.

If the B.Fld5 is not relatively unique, then you got a problem :)
You might try out to have something like this in the join in that case:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM TableA A, TableB B
WHERE
   A.Fld2 = B.Fld5 AND
   SUBSTR(A.Fld1, 1, N) = B.Fld6 AND
   A.Fld1 = B.Fld6 || B.Fld7
...
```

Idea is that you don't look from TableB rows that when concatenated match to A.Fld1, but instead take a substring from A.Fld1 so that it matches to B.Fld6. After that you need to make sure that B.Fld6 has proper index, and also would be realtively unique in TableB.
You can obviously extend that to apply same pattern for B.Fld7, i.e:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM TableA A, TableB B
WHERE
   A.Fld2 = B.Fld5 AND
   SUBSTR(A.Fld1, 1, N) = B.Fld6 AND
   SUBSTR(A.Fld1, N, LENGTH(A.Fld1)) = B.Fld7
...
```

In the JOIN above, it might be enough to have index for TableB that starts with most selective value from B.Fld5, B.Fld6 and B.Fld7.

HTH.

Comment: Outstanding lesson. I have been instructed to think down this road as I write SQL, and I am getting there.  The query runs "in a flash" in my SQL tool, but, with all of the processing around it in the PRG program, 5 seconds isn't too bad for what I am up against. See my response to Deb for where I am. Thanks Again!

Comment: 5 seconds sounds already quite a good response time for getting tens of thousands of rows out of millions.
Remember that when you play around with data, after the first query the data you read might be in database memory (buffer pools). So you might want to change the date intervals a bit as you test different queries. This way you ensure that you don't hit the data in memory but need to do disk access (i.e. worst case). I would assume that this is the case when you take that query in production use anyway.
Obviously one optimization approach is to increase database buffer pools as well...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select DISTINCT B.Fld1, B.Fld2, B.Fld3, B.Fld4,
A.Fld1, A.Fld2, A.Fld3, A.Fld4, A.Fld5, A.Fld6, A.Fld7, A.Fld8, A.Fld9
From 
(
select * from TableA where ((Fld7 BETWEEN <from-date> and <to-date>)
Or (Fld5 BETWEEN <from-date> and <to-date>))
) A, 
TableB B
Where A.Fld2 = B.Fld5
And A.Fld1 = B.Fld6 || B.Fld7
```

and this

```
Select DISTINCT c.Fld1, c.Fld2, c.Fld3, c.Fld4,
c.Fld1, c.Fld2, c.Fld3, c.Fld4, c.Fld5, c.Fld6, c.Fld7, c.Fld8, c.Fld9
From 
(
select * from TableA A, TableB B
Where A.Fld2 = B.Fld5
And A.Fld1 = B.Fld6 || B.Fld7
)c
where ((c.Fld7 BETWEEN <from-date> and <to-date>)
Or (c.Fld5 BETWEEN <from-date> and <to-date>))
```

Hope at least one of them will be faster.

**EDIT**

Here either the join is the bottle neck or the tablescan because of date comparison is the issue. So the idea is to extract required rows first and then process them further with join or date comparison. This will limit the no. of total rows that need processing rather than processing the entire table of rows.

Comment: I greatly appreciate this input.  It has definitely helped me beat down the learning curve.  Unfortunately, it looks like the total records and the way the process is currently in place, is going to make it necessary to do some redesign.  I am experimenting with the "WITH" statement right now, but it really looks like something else is going to have to be done. Again, I appreacite your input.

Comment: In that case just include the sub query in your with block and i suggest you use a parameter to further reduce the no of records

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might try is to put parentheses around each of the clauses in the where clause.  Instead of:

```
Where A.Fld2 = B.Fld5 And A.Fld1 = B.Fld6 || B.Fld7 And ((A.Fld7 BETWEEN <from-date> and <to-date>) Or (A.Fld5 BETWEEN <from-date> and <to-date>)) 

Where (A.Fld2 = B.Fld5) And ((A.Fld1 = B.Fld6) || B.Fld7) And ((A.Fld7 BETWEEN <from-date> and <to-date>) Or (A.Fld5 BETWEEN <from-date> and <to-date>))
```

The question is the precedence of the || operator.  If it is the same as the AND, then you are doing essentially the following:

```
WHERE (A.Fld2 = B.fld5) or B.fld7
```

The "or" is prioritized after the AND, which results in a cross join . . . and that would have very bad performance.

Comment: Thanks! Please see mt response to Deb.